# How do I convert Excel to DAX Formula?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, excellibrary

In my current project I am migrating Excel reports to Power BI, I need help converting the Excel formulas to DAX

Excel

```
COUNTIFS($K:$K,"*",$L:$L,E$31,$CS:$CS,1$D:$D,$E$15)

SUMIFS($AU:$AU,$L:$L,E$31,$CI:$CI, "Yes",$D:$D,$E$15)/1000

IFERROR((SUMIFS($AU:$AU,$L:$L,E$31,$CI:$CI, "Yes",$D:$D,$E$15,$P:$P," Key Launch Under Existing Hero")/1000)/E36,0)

COUNTIFS(`$BH$11:$BH$1001,"Commercial Innovation",$H$11:$H$1001,F$31,$C$11:$C$1001,$E$15,$BP$11:$BP$1001,"1")

SUMIFS($BB$11:$BB$1001$C$11:$C$1001,$E$15,$H$11:$H$1001,G$31,$BH$11:$BH$1001,"Commercial Innovation")/1000

COUNTIFS(OFFSET($L$10,0,0,10000,1),$D65,OFFSET($AL$10,0,INDEX($AL$6:$AU$6,MATCH($D$59,$AL$10:$AU$10,0)),10000,1),">0",OFFSET($CI$10,0,0,10000,1),"Yes",OFFSET($D$10,0,0,10000,1),$E$15)

IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS($CJ:$CJ, $K:$K, "*",$L:$L,$D113,$D:$D,$E$15), "-")
```

Comment: Its very hard to tell from your example, a table would be better. you need to look at COUNT and SUM in DAX, using CALCULATE and FILTER
So Excel COUNTIF(D:D, "Red") would be in power bi CALCULATE(COUNT(column), FILTER(table, column = "Red))

Answer (score 1):

you can use Calculate function for any conditional calculation in DAX.
There is no references and cells like excel in Power BI therefore there is no OFFSET or INDEX in Power BI but you can explain you problem in a table for find a solution instead of Offset and Index.
For another formulas that you want:

**Excel Countifs:**

```
COUNTIFS($K:$K,"*",$L:$L,E$31,$CS:$CS,1$D:$D,$E$15)
```

**DAX:**

```
Measure Name = Calculate(count(K_Column), tbl_name[k_Column]="*",
tbl_name[L_Column]=E31_Value,...)
```

**Excel Sumifs:**

```
SUMIFS($AU:$AU,$L:$L,E$31,$CI:$CI, "Yes",$D:$D,$E$15)/1000
```

**DAX:**

```
Measure Name = Calculate(Sum(AU), tbl_name[L_Column]=E31_Value,
tbl_name[CI_Column]="Yes",...)
```

**and you have iferror in DAX like excel:**

```
iferror(calculate(sum(column_name), filter1, filter2))
```

There is a filter function in DAX for create a filtered table We don't have something like that in Excel.